# How to query timestamptz in postgres and compare with time.Time in go?

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I'm using Postgres 10 and with a dummy table

```
CREATE TABLE demo (now timestamptz);
```

When using jmoiron/sqlx, I can't compare `time.Time` with `timestamptz`. The sample code is

```
db, _ := sqlx.Connect("postgres", dsn)
now, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2019-03-22T00:00:00Z")
db.Exec("INSERT INTO demo (now) VALUES ($1)", now)

query := "SELECT timezone('utc', now) as now FROM demo"
type row struct{ Now time.Time }
var rows []row
if err := db.Select(&rows, query); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
want := []row{ { Now: now } }
if !reflect.DeepEqual(rows, want) {
    log.Printf("want: %v; got: %v", want, rows)
}
```

I got results saying they are not equal in the last step

```
 want: [{0 2019-03-22 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}]
 got: [{0 2019-03-22 00:00:00 +0000 +0000}]
```

What should I do make `reflect.DeepEqual` think both are equal?

Comment: Never use `reflect.DeepEqual` for time comparison. It will (almost) never work, due to the [monotonic clock](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks) fields embedded in the time structure, to say nothing of differences in timezone representations. Instead use [`time.Equal`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use DeepEqual for time comparison. You should compare times using the `time` package. You should do:

```
now.Equal(rows[0].Now)
```